# What can be done about the problem of bullying in post-PhD academia?

Tags: postdocs, tenure-track, academic-life, non-tenure, personal-misconduct

I recently wrote a piece of advice to a bullied postdoc that made me sad.

Abbreviated, [original here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124362/aggressive-co-worker-and-bullying-at-the-lab/124371#124371),

> "It is unlikely you can fight this culture, and academic settings have
>   practically no good ways to address bullying of this nature. If you
>   find what seems to be one, look for evidence that it has worked for
>   past students. Recently. Your best strategy? Leave. Keep your head
>   down, and start planning your exit now."

I personally have seen no post PhD success stories that include bullies being stood up to and punished by the system, AND the individuals bullied subsuquently moving forward in their academic careers. I facilitated a conversation with a dozen colleges last night which kept that total. Zero. We all work with different highly ranked R1 universities in the northeast. Between us, we have worked within over 30 US universities.  We agreed that bullies inhabit different roles in academia than in industry and government settings. We also agreed that the topic of bullies is more taboo in post-doctoral academic settings than in upper echelon government and industry settings.

Two questions we think are key:

What unique aspects of post- PhD academic culture allow bullies to persist?

What can be done to end this?

Comment: Also, to the first indignant bully to write here: welcome. Seriously. I suspect you are an important part of this discussion.

Comment: I suspect the contrast with industry is simply a matter of your personal experience. Check out Workplace.SE and you'll find bullies aren't something special to Academia. That said, I don't really feel this question is anything but a rant and prompt for discussion, which makes it not a great SE question even if it's an important issue.

Comment: Academia is very different from one place to another - where have you experienced this?

Comment: I have never worked with any "bullies." Some people that never answer their email, but no bullies. It's not really "a paradise."

Comment: _This stands in contrast to my experience with industry, where "no brilliant assholes" has made its mark: bullies in companies are generally dealt with when identified._ Then your experience must be different from mine. I'd been there for decades, lots of bullies.

Comment: This would be a better question with the "Why" removed, or replaced by "When". Otherwise, you'll get a lot of "I have been in academia for X years and have never encountered any bullies" responses (case in point: in pure math I have never encountered any bullies at MIT or UMN, and only some hints of infighting at LMU).

Comment: @BryanKrause, I do agree with you, however, why do you think is a great SE question? Just contemplate in the OP's question: What can be done to end this phenomenon, which I think become so much disseminated across the globe, I have been now in 4 four different countries in a different continent, and the problem still exists. I think this most important question and the root of the problem that there is no transparency and the PI has the supreme power. I do think there is must be a supreme council for academia all over the world that is completely biased and consider these cases.

Comment: @Monkia https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask SE just isn't good for discussion-based questions like this one.

Comment: Okay but this doesn't negate that the question is important and simply you can ask OP to edit the question! We are not robots, we are human! Rules step down when we see the emotions of outrage likely in the OP, we must have an informative discussion about this issue, and I have witnessed many times in the platform avoiding discussing it

Comment: @Industrademic, can please you edit your question?

Comment: @Monkia I agree it's important and said so in my comment. I don't see a good way to amend this into a non-discussion broad-based question, so I don't have a specific suggestion for an edit. Not every important question is appropriate for StackExchange in my opinion.

Comment: That is your opinion, and my opinion it is important and I think this platform must change the strategy that everyone has a high rank can do what s(he) personally think of the OPs' questions, this is kind of bullying in itself and this is my opinion.

Comment: @Monkia The place to raise those concerns is on Meta rather than a comment thread.

Comment: @Monkia SE is a strict Q&A platform looking for objective answers, not a discussion forum. Why must everything is on SE when there are alternatives like Quora and Reddit for open-ended discussion/brainstorming question?

Comment: @monkia, trying. I have a post in Meta where I'm trying to understand why this is inadmissible and how to ask it. I mean, if everything must have a discrete answer, this SE cannot exist, as it necessarily addresses culture.

Comment: And @monkia, I did invite the indignant bullies in my first comment. ;)

Comment: @Industrademic, can you please forward the link of the question on Meta, I am curious to know where this crucial topic is going for as I think academia systems is chaos and corrupted and we need to find out practical ideas and applicable solutions.

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/why-is-this-question-about-bullying-still-on-hold?noredirect=1#comment13423_4426

Comment: It's interesting. I'm also interested that the pro-bully response below is no longer shown. Fascinating.  It's a microcosm, in some ways, of how academic institutions are failing at this hard, messy problem.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure that I accept your premise that "academia is paradise for bullies". There are bullies in academia, but also there are bullies elsewhere.

Nevertheless, we can meaningfully ask if there are any dynamics in academia which may help bullies prosper. I can think of two particular ones:

1. Some parts of academia have a culture of tolerating and in some cases venerating "the brilliant asshole", i.e. the arrogant academic who routinely belittles and harangues students and junior researchers but we all go along because they've done some really important work in their field. Your question hints at this and user104075's answer kind of exemplifies it. This attitude can lead people who should really be seeking to prevent bullying to shrug it off with a "but that's just who he is".
2. Strong disparity in job security between the people at the top and bottom of the ladder, perhaps more so than in other professions. Postdocs are constantly, painfully, aware, that their contract will be up soon, and you need to get some papers, and there are hundreds of applicants to every faculty position etc etc. This makes junior researchers wary of leaving a position, even if it is terrible, and extra nervous of not getting a good recommendation letter from their present supervisor. I have heard of academics boasting of keeping their postdocs on short contracts, so that they can use the threat of not renewing it to get their postdocs to work unreasonable hours.
   On the other hand, in some places, a tenured professor is virtually unfireable, short of outright academic fraud or serious criminality. So while the person on the end of the bullying faces huge risks from making a fuss, the bully may not face much consequence even if it does come out.

What can be done to mitigate these?

- Use the wellbeing of an academic's students and postdocs as a criterion on which to evaluate them for funding and tenure
- Better job security for postdocs - i.e. work towards a norm of longer contracts where possible. If this means that there are fewer postdocs, but they work under better conditions, I think that would be reasonable. Others will disagree.
- Universities can implement robust anti-bullying policies with meaningful sanctions against academics who violate them.